# see the packets sent in nrf connect debugger

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet-sniffers, nrf-connect

I'm trying to see what a specific app is sending via Bluetooth.

I open the app on my android phone and the NRF-Connect app and started debugging the connection.
when I'm using the app I can see the logs that I'm receiving but not the ones I **send**.

How can I see what my phone is sending?

NRF also allows cloning the device's services. Is there an option to mimic the device, so the app would connect to my phone and not the real device then I would be able to see the packets I receive?

other options not including NRF-Connect app are welcome.
I tried several sniffer applications but for some reason, it did not show the packets sent. do you have a recommendation for a good sniffer for the phone or computer?

Comment: Are you on Android? Could you use BTsnoop logs? https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-logs

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the BTSnoops log that ukBaz mentioned, you can use [nRF Logger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.log&hl=en_GB&gl=US&pli=1) if you haven't tried that already. It should show you a complete log including INFO, DEBUG, and WARNING/ERROR messages.

If you want a good cheap sniffer then I highly recommend using a nordic devkit as a sniffer. There are detailed steps on how to achieve this [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-sniffer-for-bluetooth-le). As shown in the link, you need to purchase one of the suggested boards and then click "Docummentation" for more information.